# Deploy Server hosted Blazor .NET6 to traditional webhost

Tags: deployment, ftp, blazor-server-side

I have created a Server hosted Blazor web application with .NET6. Now I want to publish to my web hotel that runs Windows Servers. I interact with them through a Plesk platform. They implicitly use IIS under the hood. I have an FTP area to deploy to which works fine for the other webs I have created before.

I use Rider so I don't have any fancy publishing wizards like Visual Studio, but I assume it should work fine using plain dotnet commands as well.

I ran the `dotnet publish` command and get the publish folder that I read should be enough for deployment. Then i copied all content to the FTP area and hoped everything would just work. It did not.

I have some specific questions:

1. Does Blazor .NET6 demands a special version of underlying IIS?
2. The server has Framework 4.7.2 installed but if I use a self contained deployment I guess the server installed version doesn't matter? I assumed the necessary .NET version will be included in the publish?
3. I notice to my surprise that all my appsettings files are included in the publish content. I assumed the relevant appsettings would be merged into one that should be used for production. How should that be handled?
4. It seems all Microsoft deployment guides assume Azure. In my company I can not use that. We are left with the traditional hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have solved my problems! The most crucial part was to enable full error printouts on server web by setting an environment flag. It was NOT documented on the publish page with command switches but was very helpful in finding the cause of my problems.

By adding a switch to the publish command a new section is added to the resulting web.config file:

`dotnet publish --framework net6.0 --configuration Release  /p:EnvironmentName=Development`

This will add the environmentVariables section under aspNetCore:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SqueedEmployee.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

1. You can indeed deploy self-contained which means all assemblies you need are included. Everything is included in the `\bin\Release\net6.0\publish` folder. Just copy to FTP area.
2. See above.
3. I am still a bit confused how the appsettings should be handled.
4. Conclusion is that traditional hosting works fine :)